# Como recuperar dados de um DatePicket adicionar ao Banco de Dados MySQL/JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, javafx

Estou tentando recuperar os dados de um DatePicker em JAVAFX e por em meu banco de dados, mas não consigo converter de um jeito certo :(

```
    // Desse modo dá certo
    String cpf = cadastro_alunoCPF.getText();
    aluno.setNome(cadastro_alunoNome.getText());


   // Tentei por esse metodo mas não deu certo
   // LocalDate value = cadastro_alunoDataNasc.getValue();
   // aluno.setDataNasc(value);
```

[image: DatePicket]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui simplesmente colocando:

```
 LocalDate localDate = aluno_data_nasc.getValue();
 java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
 aluno.setDataNasc(sqlDate);
```

Retornando assim a data do tipo "dd-mm-yy" do jeito que o SQL suporta

Answer (score 1):

Segundo esta [fonte](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/), o JPA 2.1 não suporta nativamente a nova API Date e Time introduzida com o Java 8.

A explicação do autor é a seguinte:

> The answer is simple, JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8 and the Date and Time API simply didn’t exist at that point in time. Therefore the @Temporal annotation can only be applied to attributes of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.

A solução apresentada pela mesma fonte supracitada é usar o AttributeConverter (créditos ao autor)

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

Qualquer problema adicional sugiro ler o artigo na íntegra para mais informações.

Outras fontes:
https://blog.tecsinapse.com.br/usando-localdate-java-8-no-hibernate4-jpa-2-1-972c463a44f9